# pass html object to function after it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small list I made in behind code and I i have an onclick thats fired when a button is hit (used  tag for buttons). I would like to know how to pass the object to my onclick function so I can toggle its class. So something likes this:

```
   <script "text/javascript">
             function navButtonClick() {
                 $(this).toggleClass("is-open");

                alert("Yay!");

                 }
    </script>
```

A person on another forum said that code should work but nothing seems to happen..

Here's what my behind code writes into the html:

```
  <div id="sidebar">
        <nav>
  <h2>Sites</h2>
  <ul id="navMenu">

     <li class="toggle"><a href="javascript:navButtonClick();">Stanislaus</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
           <li><a href="#" class="active">Bob</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: `toggleClass` is jQuery. Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming by the toggleClass that you're using JQuery, so you can just use .on('click') instead of trying to make it into a function call, but it'd be easier if you assign the toggle class to the a element instead of the li.

http://jsfiddle.net/22eYu/

```
$('a.toggle').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("is-open");
    alert("yay");
});
```

Comment: would i need to remove my "ref = "javascript:navButtonClick"?

Comment: @WillTuttle Yeah it would become unnecessary. Just make it like this, <a class="toggle" href="#">Stanislaus</a>. I updated my fiddle to show you http://jsfiddle.net/22eYu/1/

Comment: @WillTuttle yes, if you are using the on binding you no longer would need the link click because it is automatically going to call this function.  This will work the best if you want this to happen to all clicked links, however if that is the case you can just do this all via CSS. `a:visited` will work just like this but won't do the alert.

Comment: i changed the href to "#" but nothing seems to happe now

Comment: @WillTuttle Did you change the "toggle" class from the li element to the a element? And did you also add in the code that I posted? Take another look at that jsfiddle link from my last comment, I changed it to "#" and it works.

Comment: Just noticed in Firefox editor that it says [13:58: TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Comment: I fixed the error.., but still not getting the function to fire

Comment: @WillTuttle Can you post your code then so I can see exactly what you changed it to? Just throw it into a jsfiddle or something and post the link

Comment: I found the problem, I was placing the function in the wrong place in the file >.<

Comment: This is what ended up working for me:                    $(this).parents.toggleClass('is-open');

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass `this` to `onclick` and then use it in the function.

### **DEMO: *[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/4MhYf/2/)***

**JS:**

```
<script "text/javascript"> 
    function navButtonClick(clicked) {
        $(clicked).toggleClass("is-open");

        alert("Yay!");
    } 
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="navMenu">
    <li class="toggle"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="navButtonClick(this)">Stanislaus</a>

        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Bob</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.is-open{
    background-color: red;
}
```

### However, It appears you just need the following CSS:

**CSS:** *In here just put your CSS class `.is-open`*

```
a:visited {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: for someone reason "onclick" doesnt work for me, but putting the function in "href" does?

Comment: `you say potato i say potato`, it is the same thing really, but what browser are you using?

Comment: firefox, for the moment

Answer (score 0):

You may have scoping problems. Does this work?

```
<script "text/javascript">
         window.navButtonClick = function(el) {
             $(el).toggleClass("is-open");

            alert("Yay!");

             }
</script>

...
<a href="#" onclick="window.navButtonClick(this);">Stanislaus</a>
...
```

Comment: the alert gets fired, but nothing else happens. Just to test, how would I print the alert to say "SDtanislaus"?

Comment: See my edited answer and change the contents of the navButtonClick function to `alert(el.innerHTML)`.

Comment: both alert(el.innerHTML)  and   alert($("el").innerHtml);
are giving me an "undefined" error